# How to block iOS screen capture on intune

Tags: ios, mdm, intune

I use Microsoft Teams.

Currently, we used the app policy using intune. When using Android's device, screen capture is blocked.

However, if you use Teams app on iOS devices, you cannot block screen capture.

I want to block screen capture when I use Teams app on iOS devices.

Please let me know when the update will be made.
Also, please let me know if there is a good way to solve my problem.

Please.

Comment: Blocking screen capture is not a policy option for iOS. Blocking screen capture is pointless anyway unless you can guarantee that the user doesn't have a camera with them.

Comment: It's not the answer I want, but thank you for the reply.
You said that blocking screen capture means nothing if the user doesn't have a camera, but I would like to ask why MS supports screen capture for Android.
I want to prevent screen capture function in the user's team's app using iOS device . I want to use the app protection policy through intune.

Comment: Any MDM, including InTune, can only deliver the management policies supported by the device manufacturer. Apple doesn't have a policy to block screen capture (since it doesn't really achieve anything); the user can simply photograph their screen.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
1. The policy of blocking iOS screenshots will not be updated in the future, right?
2. I wonder if you could explain why iOS is not available when Android is possible.

Comment: 1. I wouldn't imagine so, but only Apple can say.  2. Only Apple can say for iOS, but it is probably "you tell us how you stop someone taking a photograph of the screen and we'll make the policy available".  You would have to ask Google why it is available for Android.

Comment: What about blocking screen capture because you don’t want inTune (or a malicious actor who has compromised your institution’s inTune administration) to be able to capture screenshots? It’s my understanding that inTune has this capability and your institution could potentially use it… so on a personal device this weirds me out to have my corporate overlords (or bad actors) having the ability to pry into my personal life. Maybe I’m wrong about that? Does inTune have the capability to take screenshots?